# Optimize custom double.parse()

Tags: c#, performance, parsing, reinventing-the-wheel, floating-point

In my company's code, they use `double.tryParse()` which is quite good but sets too much security for our needs. As we sometimes have to parse a few billion strings, I came up with this code which is a little bit faster (10%) but I have the feeling that it's not at its best... Unfortunately, this kind of stuff require more knowledge than I have.

```
private static double GetDoubleValue(string input)
{
    double n = 0;
    int decimalPosition = input.Length;
    bool separatorFound = false;
    bool negative = input[0] == '-';
    for (int k = (negative ? 1 : 0); k < input.Length; k++)
    {
        char c = input[k];

        if (c == '.' || c == ',')
        {
            if (separatorFound)
                return Double.NaN;
            decimalPosition = k + 1;
            separatorFound = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(c))
                return Double.NaN;
            n = (n * 10) + (c - '0');
        }
    }
    return ((negative ? -1 : 1) * n) / CustomPow(10, input.Length - decimalPosition);
}

private static double CustomPow(int num, int exp)
{
    double result = 1.0;
    while (exp > 0)
    {
        if (exp%2 == 1)
            result *= num;
        exp >>= 1;
        num *= num;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I note that you do not parse doubles in exponential format, you do not parse infinities, and so on. Is this intentional?

Comment: @EricLippert yes it is, my input data is or a real number (no concept like infinity) or an error (like a bunch of letter or mis-formated number)

Comment: If you really want to get more performance you could try to experiment with branching/branch prediction. The custom return-statements can probably slow you down, so you could try to set an error-variable to true inside the loop, but keep parsing and return error afterwards... Branch prediction, instruction pipelining and caching can do wonders on simple for-loops with huge iteration-count so you could try a little around there...

Comment: You should look at my answer, I have now removed output as double to make sure there is no possible floating error introduced. I now use 2 long variables.

Comment: This question could have gone to [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) too :)

Comment: @HannoBinder, true but codegolf doesn't care about speed :-)

Comment: Overall I think with @Fredous latest solution you can get some performance, but the biggest gain will be using parallel-API and running on 4/8 Threads each working on its own share of your billions of numbers. This should speed it up the most!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Naming**

Avoid single-letter or shortened form variable names. Extra characters on a variable's name are free, and work wonders for a maintenance programmer down the line.

e.g.

```
double n = 0;
```

would better be:

```
double output = 0;
```

Additionally, I'm not sold on the name `GetDoubleValue`. At no point does this method retrieve the value from anywhere. What this method does is conversion, so it should be appropriately named as such.

**Var**

Use the `var` keyword when defining local variables where the right hand side of the definition makes the type obvious. This looks cleaner and saves time when it comes to changing types during refactoring.

e.g.

```
bool separatorFound = false;
```

should be

```
var separatorFound = false;
```

You should also use `var` when declaring `foreach` and `for` loop iterators.

e.g.

```
for (int k = (negative ? 1 : 0); k < input.Length; k++)
```

should be:

```
for (var k = (negative ? 1 : 0); k < input.Length; k++)
```

**Braces**

Always use braces for if statement bodies. It's cleaner, more explicit in intent, and it's quicker should you later decide to add extra lines to the body.

e.g.

```
if (!char.IsDigit(c))
    return Double.NaN;
```

should be:

```
if (!char.IsDigit(c))
{
    return Double.NaN;
}
```

**Design**

Why have you created the function `CustomPow` when all you're really doing is repeatedly multiplying by 10? It seems this is a case of over-abstraction, unless you plan to use the method elsewhere too.

Why make `GetDoubleValue` private? It sounds like a useful function you may want to use elsewhere or in other projects. I suspect it's private because it is in a class it does not belong in, and you don't want somebody calling `StringLoader.GetDoubleValue` or something like that.

Put it in a utility class or an extension method somewhere, it doesn't make sense as a method of your string loader class or whatever.

Comment: Well that's a nice answer in many points! Any idea about performance...?

Comment: For performance I recommend chucking into visual studio's profiler first, it'll be able to help you see where you're spending most of your processing time. If you put the results up here we'll be able to better help you.

Comment: about the name of local variable, I found out that it does matter how long the name is also that is why you can see better speed after code obfuscation, all variable name are changed into a,b,c,d,etc. long parameter name DO NOT matter speed wise.

Comment: No, it doesn't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443164/does-variable-name-length-matter-for-performance-c The compiler is stripping your variables down anyway, so you should use as many characters as you need to get the information across.

Comment: I agree with the OP's decision to use a private static function, rather than a public member of a utility class.  This kind of optimization tends to be pretty tightly focused, so it probably doesn't *need* to be used in more than one place.  Since the optimizations involved are not always safe (fails to handle various cases that `double.Parse` and `double.TryParse` can handle properly), it should only be used in the special case where the OP found it to be absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Brian If that is the case, I agree. Of course, there are always other factors outside of the question, my justification of including that in the answer is that if my assumption is wrong then the OP should keep it private and would know to, but if I am right then it has been helpful to include it and would be helpful to future readers who have done something similar.

Comment: The OP's question was not related to style, but of performance, thus I downvoted your post. You're the classic case of "I don't know how to answer this, so let's just talk about coding styles."

Comment: @Krythic that is incorrect, [anything that makes the code better is fair game in Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/do-we-need-to-strictly-follow-posed-poster-requirements-when-reviewing/2578#2578). EDIT: I realize that's not a perfect source, so also check [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2154/41237)

Answer (score 9):

Nick's answer is great for style points, I just wanted to make you aware of a bug in your implementation:

`char.IsDigit(c)` will return true for numerical digits not in the Western Arabic numerals (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9). It's obscure but it will cause your program to fail. E.g.

```
var answer = GetDoubleValue("12345०7.56"); // DEVANAGARI DIGIT ZERO
// answer = 1258087.56
```

You are assuming 0-9 only (`c - '0'`) so you should only allow them. I.e. change

```
if (!char.IsDigit(c))
    return Double.NaN;
```

to

```
if (c < '0' || c > '9')
{
    return Double.NaN;
}
```

I've also added braces as I prefer that.

**Edit:**

Modifying to not use `char.IsDigit` shaves about 1% off execution time (mileage may vary).

**Further edit:**

Accidentally ran the test for speed comparison on Debug. Running on Release with no debugger 10 million iterations averaged over 5 runs:

With `char.IsDigit` - 311ms
With `c < '0' || c > '9'` - 287ms

Comment: That's cool :) but still no perf optimization

Comment: You can do things like optimize the calculation of the exp arg to `CustomPow` which makes a difference on Debug but in Release gets optimized out anyway by the looks of it.

Comment: `(c ^ '0') > 9` should be about 20% faster than `c < '0' || c > '9'` because of branch misprediction (the less comparisons the better and [`char.IsDigit`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs,041e77a953545d16) does about 3 comparisons per non-unicode digit)

Comment: @Slai Have you tested that? For well formed numbers, the branch is always false which is ideal for prediction.

Comment: @RobH I was just testing it for this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41639665/1383168 with decimal digits only.

Answer (score 7):

You could try and optimize your `CustomPow(int num, int exp)` by pre-computing some/all possible values only once:

```
double[] pow10 = new double[309];

double p = 1.0;
for ( int i = 0; i < 309; i++ ) {
  pow10[i] = p;
  p = p * 10;
}
```

Then `CustomPow10( int exp )` would just return `pow10[exp]`.

Edit:

By the way, I see that you are basically building an integer representation first (in `n`). - Why not declare `n` as `long` integer then? This would operate on an integer most of the time, which should be faster than floating point, and only at the end, when finally dividing by the power of 10, a floating point number is needed.

Edit2: This only works if all your input numbers have less than 18 digits since that's the maximum number of digits a `long` can represent.

Edit3: Please see @Fredou's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/75829/40025) for the result of combined efforts. I think his code will perform really well by now.

Comment: Well as exp is never (in my case) higher than 7 I used a switch statment with multiplication in the place of the for loop

Comment: You'd actually want to store the reciprocal (`pow10[i] = 1/p;`) so that you're multiplying (fast) instead of dividing (slow).

Answer (score 5):

This example includes the style suggestions of @nick and @RobH together with performance enhancements, namely using bitwise AND operation instead of the modulus operation.

```
private static double GetDoubleValue(string input)
{
    double output = 0;
    int inputLength = input.Length;
    int decimalPosition = inputLength;
    var hasSeperator = false;
    var isNegative = input[0] == '-';

    for (int k = (isNegative ? 1 : 0); k < inputLength; k++)
    {
        char currentCharacter = input[k];

        if (currentCharacter == '.' || currentCharacter == ',')
        {
            if (hasSeperator)
            {
                return Double.NaN;
            }
            else
            {
                hasSeperator = true;
            }

            decimalPosition = k + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            var digitValue = currentCharacter - '0';

            if (digitValue < 0 || digitValue > 9)
            {
                return Double.NaN;
            }

            output = (output * 10) + digitValue;
        }
    }

    var powDividend = CustomPow(10, inputLength - decimalPosition);
    var integer = ((isNegative ? -1 : 1) * output);

    return integer / powDividend;
}

private static double CustomPow(int num, int exp)
{
    double result = 1.0;

    while (exp > 0)
    {
        if ((exp & 1) == 1)
        {
            result *= num;
        }

        exp >>= 1;
        num *= num;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Well I suggest you a [bit of reading about this](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-number-is-odd-or-even), I was also surprised!

Comment: I cannot reproduce the article's performance results. In my test environment bitwise is always faster than a modulus operator, in Debug mode and also in the Release mode.

Comment: Then I'll test it :)

Comment: (You should always measure/benchmark in release mode, not in Debug mode.)

Comment: It seems to be about 2-3ms faster over 10 million iterations for me.

Comment: what about saving some time by calculating pow as 0.1, 0.01, ... and multiplying with the lookup? Multiply is faster than division on many systems....

Comment: @Falco I thought about that too, but because there's only one division per number parsed I figured it's not worthwhile to try and save those few CPU cycles.

Comment: Looking into http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html I find that on current Intel CPUs FDIV is about 39 clock cycles while FMUL needs only **1**. Potentially saving 38 CPU cycles per number, for 1 billion numbers @ 3.8 GHz multiplication could save a total 10 seconds of CPU time over division.

Comment: @HannoBinder Better than nothing, while we're shaving off miliseconds ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I changed the if logic to remove some branching I think, can you test on your side?

Also using the cache suggestion of **Hanno Binder**

Not using any double during string processing, only when returning the final result.

I'm gaining about 50% speed and it seem to still return proper value

Compile as **Release** under **64bits**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private readonly static double[] pow10Cache;
        static Program()
        {
            pow10Cache = new double[309];

            double p = 1.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 309; i++)
            {
                pow10Cache[i] = p;
                p /=  10;
            }
        }

        private static double GetDoubleValue(string input)
        {
            long inputLength = input.Length;
            long digitValue = long.MaxValue;
            long output1 = 0;
            long output2 = 0;
            long sign = 1;
            double multiBy = 0.0;
            int k;

            //integer part
            for (k = 0; k < inputLength; ++k)
            {
                digitValue = input[k] - 48; // '0'

                if (digitValue >= 0 && digitValue <= 9 )
                {
                    output1 = digitValue + (output1 * 10);
                }
                else if (k == 0 && digitValue == -3 /* '-' */)
                {
                    sign = -1;
                }
                else if (digitValue == -2 /* '.' */ || digitValue == -4 /* ',' */)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Double.NaN;
                }
            }

            //decimal part
            if (digitValue == -2 /* '.' */ || digitValue == -4 /* ',' */)
            {
                multiBy = pow10Cache[inputLength - (++k)];

                for (; k < inputLength; ++k)
                {
                    digitValue = input[k] - 48; // '0'

                    if (digitValue >= 0 && digitValue <= 9)
                    {
                        output2 = digitValue + (output2 * 10);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Double.NaN;
                    }
                }

                multiBy *= output2;
            }

            return sign * (output1 + multiBy);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Preparing values to test ");
            var rnd = new Random(42);
            var test = new string[10000000];
            double value;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
            {
                value = rnd.NextDouble() * 10000;
                value *= value;
                value += rnd.NextDouble();
                value *= (i % 2) == 0 ? 1 : -1;

                test[i] = value.ToString();

                if ((i % 1000000) == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(".");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" benchmarking them");
            for (int a = 1; a < 5; ++a)
            {
                var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
                {
                    GetDoubleValue(test[i]);
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Run {0} took {1}ms",a,sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }

            bool anyError = false;
            int errorCount = 0;
            Console.Write("Any error? ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
            {
                if (!string.Equals(GetDoubleValue(test[i]).ToString(), test[i]))
                {
                    if (!anyError)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" Yes");
                        anyError = true;
                    }

                    errorCount++;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} = {2}", GetDoubleValue(test[i]), test[i], string.Equals(GetDoubleValue(test[i]).ToString(), test[i]));
                    if (errorCount >= 10)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if ((i % 1000000) == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(".");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" {0}", anyError ? "" : "No");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using a lookup table - why are you still using division? Multiplication is usually faster - so you should save 0.1, 0.01, ... in you array and multiply!

Comment: @Falco, I made the change and it does help.

Comment: @Fredou Could you try and check if changing `double output = 0.0;` to `int output = 0;` makes a difference?

Comment: @HannoBinder, it will make a difference. The code would not be able to convert 12345.123456678 anymore, logic in the code will make 12345123456678, this number will not fit into a int

Comment: Of course you're right. I was assuming that the OP's number would not have more than 7 *digits*, but he actually only said that it will not have more than 7 *decimals*. Yet, *if* the input's digits can all fit into an `int` or `long` this optimization could be viable.

Comment: One could add a simple if in the beginning - if input.length < 20 use the version with long.

Comment: @HannoBinder, using a long instead if double for the output make it 2x slower

Comment: @Falco, adding an if and using a long instead slow down the whole thing

Comment: strange... I had a speedup of 10% with a long instead of double. It should be faster on 64bit, since it is a simple add... Did you also change digitValue to long ? I also changed sign to long and did the last line as output * sign * pow10cache[...]

Comment: @Falco I was doing all my testing under 32bits (anycpu) :-) doing it under 64bits change things :-)

Comment: @Falco, I have updated my code which now I think is way better than before

Comment: @Fredou Thanks for checking the `long` approach. - I think, with your latest modifications, you now made a pretty good implementation performance-wise :)

Answer (score 5):

Two comments regarding your algorithm:

Note that your algorithm can introduce errors in borderline cases like `"1.00000000000000000000000000000000"` which is parsed to `Infinity`, or `"1.0000000000000000"` which is parsed to `5333562.5371386623` (!).

Especially the second behavior is caused by a bug in your `CustomPow` function which keeps `num` as `int`, which can overflow easily for exponents above 16 (`CustomPow(10, 16)` returns 1874919424).

But even if this is fixed, extremely borderline cases like `GetDoubleValue("1." + new string('0', 310))` return `Infinity`. (Note that Fredou’s solution is worse here, it dies with `IndexOutOfRangeException`.)

(The problem is that you are composing the whole number without regard to decimal separator, which might overflow prior to the final division.)

Improved algorithm, which also has better performance (by my experiments, ~30 % better than your original, ~20 % better than Fredou’s):

```
private static double QuickDoubleParse(string input)
{
    double result = 0;
    var pos = 0;
    var len = input.Length;
    if (len == 0) return Double.NaN;
    char c = input[0];
    double sign = 1;
    if (c == '-')
    {
        sign = -1;
        ++pos;
        if (pos >= len) return Double.NaN;
    }

    while (true) // breaks inside on pos >= len or non-digit character
    {
        if (pos >= len) return sign * result;
        c = input[pos++];
        if (c < '0' || c > '9') break;
        result = (result * 10.0) + (c - '0');
    }

    if (c != '.' && c != ',') return Double.NaN;
    double exp = 0.1;
    while (pos < len)
    {
        c = input[pos++];
        if (c < '0' || c > '9') return Double.NaN;
        result += (c - '0') * exp;
        exp *= 0.1;
    }
    return sign * result;
}
```

The algorithm parses the integral and fractional parts separately. I have also tried to implement it using `unsafe` features, but the improvement is inconclusive, but you may try:

```
private unsafe static double UnsafeQuickDoubleParse(string input)
{
    double result = 0;
    var len = input.Length;
    if (len == 0) return Double.NaN;
    double sign = 1;
    fixed (char* pstr = input)
    {
        var end = (pstr + len);
        var pc = pstr;
        char c = *pc;
        if (c == '-')
        {
            sign = -1;
            ++pc;
            if (pc >= end) return Double.NaN;
        }

        while (true) // breaks inside on pos >= len or non-digit character
        {
            if (pc >= end) return sign * result;
            c = *pc++;
            if (c < '0' || c > '9') break;
            result = (result * 10.0) + (c - '0');
        }

        if (c != '.' && c != ',') return Double.NaN;
        double exp = 0.1;
        while (pc < end)
        {
            c = *pc++;
            if (c < '0' || c > '9') return Double.NaN;
            result += (c - '0') * exp;
            exp *= 0.1;
        }
    }
    return sign * result;
}
```

Comment: Nice one! In my data, the exp is never > 7, I don't deal with big number

Comment: Just note that the absolute magnitude of the number does not matter, only the length of the string; my examples are all equal to one, just written in a roundabout way with a lot of decimal places.

Comment: your algorithm have rounding issue i think, if you use my main code in my answer and replace my parse with your parse, there is error like this showing up: input: 78.1784928767842 output:78.1784928767841, input: 87.5688321364898 output:87.5688321364897, input: -68.6253328195891 -68.625332819589, etc...

Comment: @Thomas, don't forget to do quality check with my answer or any others answers to be sure what get in get properly out.

Comment: This algorithm does have rounding problems due to inexactness of floating point numbers. Each time you calculate `result += (c - '0') * exp` you introduce a bit more error.

Comment: @RobH The Problem lies in the repeatet multiplication of exp. Since 0.1*0.1*...*0.1 introduces a slight error, each added digit also adds a slight error, which can add up to a significant digit change!

Comment: @Falco - As both `result` and `exp` are doubles, they are both a source of error.

Comment: @RobH yes - but if you want to parse a **double** that error is inherently there - there is NO WAY AROUND that. So the problem here is, there is a bigger error than neccessary, and it stems from repeated multiplication, which makes it bigger.

Answer (score 2):

<s>It doesn't seem that anybody has mentioned this.</s>

> ```
> if (c == '.' || c == ',')
> ```

You seem to be making the assumption that *any string* containing a period or comma is able to be parsed into a double. How will your code react to me sending this string into it?

> It seems this is a case of over-abstraction, unless you plan to use the method elsewhere too.

---

I was wrong about that, but that's because it wasn't clear what was going on. Why wasn't it clear? *Lack of brackets.*

> ```
> if (c == '.' || c == ',')
> {
>     if (separatorFound)
>         return Double.NaN;
>     decimalPosition = k + 1;
>     separatorFound = true;
> }
> ```

Brackets would have made it instantly clear that you were returning and not just letting the code blithely stumble on. Heck, even a new line after the `return` statement would have cleared that up.

---

I'm not sure, but it doesn't seem to me that you considered that someone could/would pass some strange string into your method that would potentially break it.

You *definitely* didn't consider that [many cultures use spaces as separators](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html) instead of commas. I don't know the right way to do what you're attempting, but I'm convinced that this isn't it.

---

I take it back that "I'm not sure you're considering strings that could break your method". You're *definitely* not. It turns out that you're not considering group separators at all. You probably should be. These are strings after all. These are numbers in a format that could be expected to be as people would write them. All of the following numbers in string format will break your code.

> ```
> 4 294 967 295,000 (Canadian)
> 4,294,967,295.000 (US - English)
> 4 294 967.295,000 (German)
> 4.294.967.295,000 (Norwegian)
> ```

Comment: Well I've got this piece of code `if (!char.IsDigit(c)) return Double.NaN;` which will kill your phrase down :p but +1 for space separator ! (which I'll not consider as it's not in my data)

Comment: Ahh you're right. I overlooked that. Probably due to a lack of brackets there... Will update my answer when I have a sec.

Comment: He's accepting either a period or comma as decimal point, not a group separator - his code has no support at all for group separators.

Comment: @Random832 doesn't that mean a string like `"200,123.45"` would break the code?

Comment: @RubberDuck yes, it would. He apparently doesn't have any strings like that. This is apparently meant to be very specialized for a specific dataset, not a general parsing function. Honestly, I'm more surprised he's bothering to handle both possible decimal points at all.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry I don't have enough time to write and benchmark everything, so here are just some ideas:

Some approaches to get more performance:

1. Use C# parallel execution mechanics if you are converting millions of Strings to doubles. The executions are all independent, so on a quad core you should roughly save 70% of your execution time on one core.
2. Operator optimizations: Since the parsing essentially comes down to a very basic loop which is executed very often you can try to micro-optimize thinking of the processor architecture. Multiplications are usually faster than divisions. Additions are even faster and shifts are fastest.
3. Pipelining/Branch prediction: You processor usually tries to overlap as many instructions as possible, if they are not dependent on each other. If you have branches the branch predictor tries to predict the outcome and if it is wrong you usually get a big performance penalty. In a loop you have a bottleneck if variables are written in one iteration and read in the next. But modern processors can even do fancy stuff like passing results from one calculation directly into the next.

So what could probably speed up the whole process would be to eliminate complex branching on dependent variables. Code will follow if I have the time...